# Prevent menu from rolling up when its sub-menu is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have a vertical menu here, which in turn has primary and secondary sub-menus. When the primary or secondary sub-menu is clicked, the whole menu will be closed. I want the sub-menu to stay open when clicked.

e.g.: vertical menu > sub-menu first > sub-menu second (clicked), the page opens up and the menu stays open.

```js
$(function () {
    $('.showFirst').click(function () {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
        $('.showFirst').not(this).find('ul').slideUp();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('.showSecond').click(function () {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
    });
    
    $('ul li ul').click(function () {
        $('ul li ul li ul').slideUp();
    });
    $('ul li ul li ul').click(function (e) {
        $("ul li ul li ul").slideUp();
        $("ul li ul").slideUp();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a {
    color: black;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #aaa;
    text-decoration: none;
}
span.sb-caret {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
}
span.sb-caret {
    /* Caret Down */
    border-top: 5px solid;
    border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
}
.sb-submenu-active > span.sb-caret {
    /* Caret Up */
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid;
}
ul li > ul {
    display: none;
    /*  border:1px solid black; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="showFirst"><a href="#">First<span class="sb-caret"></span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Second</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Second</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Second</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="showFirst"><a href="#">First<span class="sb-caret"></span></a>
        <ul>
            <li class="showSecond"><a href="#">Second<span class="sb-caret"></span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">third</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">third</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Second</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Second</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you may clicked anchor tag so it leads to reload the page.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but here is a jsFiddle of the puzzle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/Lhhf17co/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're even able to keep track of all of those `ul li ul...` strings...but don't. That's setting yourself up to easily make mistakes if your DOM changes even slightly, or if you mistype something. Add classes to your markup to make it easier to traverse and reference elements. In this case, a distinct class for each level of `<ul>` would make things much easier.

Then, you simply have to be selective about which menus you collapse and when. You'll notice the only real change here is that I replaced your `ul li ul...` click handlers with these:

```
$('.tier-2').click(function (e) {
    $('.tier-3').slideUp();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

That code ensures that anytime a level-two list is clicked, all level-three ones collapse.

```
$('.tier-3').click(function (e) {
    $('.tier-2, .tier-3')
        .not(this)
        .not($(this).closest('.tier-2'))
        .slideUp();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This fragment ensures that if a level-three list is clicked, all other level-three lists collapse except this one, and all level-two lists collapse except the parent of this one.

See the full example below.

```js
$(function () {
    $('.showFirst').click(function () {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
        $('.showFirst').not(this).find('ul').slideUp();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('.showSecond').click(function () {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
    });
    
    $('.tier-2').click(function (e) {
        $('.tier-3').slideUp();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('.tier-3').click(function (e) {
        $('.tier-2, .tier-3')
            .not(this)
            .not($(this).closest('.tier-2'))
            .slideUp();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a {
    color: black;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #aaa;
    text-decoration: none;
}
span.sb-caret {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
}
span.sb-caret {
    /* Caret Down */
    border-top: 5px solid;
    border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
}
.sb-submenu-active > span.sb-caret {
    /* Caret Up */
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid;
}
ul li > ul {
    display: none;
    /*  border:1px solid black; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="showFirst"><a href="#">First<span class="sb-caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="tier-2">
            <li><a href="#">Second</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Second</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Second</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="showFirst"><a href="#">First<span class="sb-caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="tier-2">
            <li class="showSecond"><a href="#">Second<span class="sb-caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="tier-3">
                    <li><a href="#">third</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">third</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Second</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Second</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for well explained codes and elaboration. Your code works well but I found a problem that is, my pages are separated so everything will reload again including the vertical menu. This CSS line ul li > ul {display: none;} keep reloading